# iOS: huge amount frames animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I need an advice. I have to create application with 5 objects animation at one view at once, the problem is that there are too many frames that should be displayed(1200). How can I do it non - painfully?

Comment: Please clarify. Do you have 1200 frames as image files?

Comment: I have both: separate images and sprite sheets.

Comment: I tried different ways: 1. Png files animate in UIImageView, 2.split sprite sheet on frames and animate in UIImageView.

Comment: Also did the same with sprite kit. Received memory warning all the time.

Comment: Please give more details about you're trying to do, include source code, and the details of the issues you're facing. We can't guess what you're trying to do.

Comment: It's not clear at all whether you're talking about 1200 elements on screen at the same time, or 1200 successive frames. If the latter, it's not clear where those come from.

Comment: I found the solution, but thanks everyone :)  For those who have the same problem and doesn't know to solve it, use this tutorial http://mysterycoconut.com/blog/2011/01/cag1/